# How to move to the next page on Python Selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, screen-scraping, webdriverwait

I am trying to build a proxy scraper for a specific site, but I'm failing on move to next page.

This is the code that I'm using.

If you answer my question, please, explain me a bit about what you used and if you can, please, if there are any good tutorials for over this kind of code, provide me some:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

options = Options()
#options.headless = True     #for headless
#options.add_argument('--disable-gpu') #for headless and os win

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://hidemyna.me/en/proxy-list/")
time.sleep(10) #bypass cloudflare


tbody = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("tbody")
cell = tbody.find_elements_by_tag_name("tr")

for column in cell:
    column = column.text.split(" ")
    print (column[0]+":"+ column[1]) #ip and port

nxt = driver.find_element_by_class_name('arrow_right')
nxt.click()
```

Comment: Try `nxt = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.arrow__right>a')`. Note that there are *two underscores* in class name

Comment: Post the relevant HTML here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To move to the *next page* you can try the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, WebDriverException

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
  options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://hidemyna.me/en/proxy-list/')
  while True:
      try:
          driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='arrow__right']/a"))))
          driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='arrow__right']/a").click()
          print("Navigating to Next Page")
      except (TimeoutException, WebDriverException) as e:
          print("Last page reached")
          break
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Navigating to Next Page
  Navigating to Next Page
  Navigating to Next Page
  Navigating to Next Page
  Navigating to Next Page
  Navigating to Next Page
  Navigating to Next Page
  Navigating to Next Page
  Navigating to Next Page
  Navigating to Next Page
  Navigating to Next Page
  Navigating to Next Page
  Navigating to Next Page
  Navigating to Next Page
  Navigating to Next Page
  Navigating to Next Page
  Navigating to Next Page
  Navigating to Next Page
  Navigating to Next Page
  Navigating to Next Page
  .
  .
  .
  Navigating to Next Page
  Last page reached
  ```

Comment: @CodeIt Can you explain why this will not work on page 2?

Comment: @DebanjanB , on second page your selector will match *Previous* button instead of *Next*

Comment: tried the above but it is not working on this site. the error output is  selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <a href="/en/proxy-list/?start=64#list"></a> is not clickable at point (874, 563). Other element would receive the click: <jdiv class="hoverl_6R"></jdiv>

Comment: @Haunter Checkout my answer update and let me know the status.

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually clicking the anchor `<a>` tag. To navigate to next page you need to `click` on the `<a>` link.

You can use [find_element_by_xpath](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-xpath) like below.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content-section"]/section[1]/div/div[4]/ul/li[1]/a').click()
```

Instead of using xpath you may use css selector as suggested by another [@Andersson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53955988/how-to-move-next-page#comment94750093_53955988).

Answer (score 0):

the next button tend to vary from webpage to webpage...you will have to inspect the button and address it with xpath or beaufifulsoup

There's usually 'next page' and 'previous page'...address your xpath to 'next'